# Socket.Send best practise

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to improve some of our networking code, and here I need to use `Socket.Send`.

However, MSDN states that it's the developers own responsibility to handle retries, and since the Socket.Send method won't necessary send all data in a single request (depends on buffer size), I've decided to go with following loop:

```
try
{
    int timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Milliseconds;
    int waitTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30).Milliseconds;

    Socket socket = tcpClient.Client;
    socket.SendTimeout = timeout ;

    int offset = 0;

    while (offset != data.Length)
    {
        if (socket.Poll(waitTime , SelectMode.SelectWrite))
        {
            offset += socket.Send(data, offset, data.Length - offset, SocketFlags.None);
        }
    }
}
catch (SocketException)
{
    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

However, I'm uncertain regarding the offset, as it's zero based, which probably would result in the offset missing a single byte on every loop here, or am I wrong?

Also, are there any other best practises to be concerned about here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN Article says:

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The number of bytes sent to the
>   Socket.

So I wouldn't worry about it. My only advice for best practises is to consider using WCF, and it is a lot easier to use and much more reliable than sockets in .NET, especially for anything complex.

Comment: Ah :) Well, your code should work fine. I've done something similar in the past by incrementing an offset variable :)